Unbounded function in $L^\infty$ implies the existence of a $L^2$ function for which the product does not belong to $L^2$
Let $a: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function which is not essentially bounded (So does not belong to $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$). I need to show that there exists a function $f$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for which the function $af$ does not belong to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.
So I have to construct a function $f$ such that that the $af$ is not integrable. i.e
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|a(t)f(t)|^{2}dt = \infty$$
I am new to measure and integration theory and not quite sure how to construct this function $f$. Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Consider the sets $E_n$ given by $n \le |a(t)| < n+1$; the essential unboundness of $a$ means that there is a sequence $n_k$ st the measure $c_k$ of $E_{n_k}$ is non zero so taking $f(t)=\frac{\bar a(t)}{\sqrt c_k n^2}, t \in E_{n_k}$ and $f(t)=0$ otherwise, we get the required $f$ as you can easily check

@Conrad We have to consider the case $c_k=\infty$.

You fan also proceed by contradiction. If there was no such function $f$, then for any positive function $g=f^2\in L^1$, $\langle a^2,g\rangle \leq C$, and since the dual of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$, this would imply that $a$ is bounded.

@user that's true but of course one can take any $c_k$ at most the measure of the set so we can take $c_k=1$ if the measure is infinite

@Conrad Of course one can. But one should say that one can.
